# What do you call spelling based on grammar?

Tags: spelling, terminology

Most words in German base their spelling on pronunciation, e.g. *Mann* or English *man*, *men*. There is a second way, more common in English, e.g. *night*, where the *gh* has more to do with where the word comes from (related to German *Nacht*) than with how you pronounce it.

But there is a third method. *Männer* is spelt with an *ä* because it comes from *Mann*. The *ä* tells us that it is an *a* that has been modified and makes *Männer* much easier to recognise as the plural of *Mann* than it is to recognise *men* as the plural of *man* - which does not even look like a plural.

Is there a name for this sort of spelling that is based on grammar?

Comment: I don't quite agree with your distinction of a "third method" here: *Männer* is spelt with an *ä* rather than an *a* as this precisely corresponds with a difference in pronunciation (first "method" listed in your question). Or, if you will, it's spelt with an *ä* rather than an *e* because of "where the word comes from" (related to *Mann*; second "method" listed in your question).

Answer (score 3):

I recall the term *Stammprinzip*, the [amtliches Regelwerk](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2016_redigiert_2018.pdf) calls it *Stammschreibung* or *Schemakonstanz*. To quote from the introduction (p. 8):

> Die deutsche Rechtschreibung bezieht sich nicht nur auf die Lautung,
>   sondern sie dient auch der grafischen Fixierung von Inhalten der
>   sprachlichen Einheiten, das heißt der Bedeutung von Wortteilen, Wörtern, Sätzen und Texten. **So wird ein Wortstamm möglichst gleich geschrieben, selbst wenn er in unterschiedlicher Umgebung verschieden
>   ausgesprochen wird. Man spricht hier von Stammschreibung oder
>   Schemakonstanz.** Dies betrifft zum Beispiel die Schreibung bei Auslautverhärtung in manchen deutschen Sprachgebieten (*Rad* und *Rat*
>   werden gleich ausgesprochen, aber unterschiedlich geschrieben wegen
>   *des Rades* und *des Rates*), den Umlaut (zum Beispiel *Wand – Wände*,
>   aber *Wende*), das Zusammentreffen gleicher Konsonanten (zum Beispiel *Haussegen, fünffach, zerreißen, enttäuschen, Blinddarm*), gelegentlich auch Einzelfälle (*vier* mit langem [iː], aber *vierzehn, vierzig* trotz kurzem [ɪ]). Hingegen werden in manchen Fällen verschiedene
>   Wörter, obwohl sie gleich ausgesprochen werden, unterschiedlich geschrieben (Unterscheidungsschreibung; zum Beispiel *Saite, Seite; wieder, wider*).

As the explanation indicates, this is not seen as "spelling based on grammar" but as maintaining, as far as possible*, the spelling of a stem across word forms even if the stem is pronounced differently. So it has more to do with potentially ignoring grapheme-phoneme correspondence.

There's one obvious example where the spelling reform of 1996 has increased similarity among word forms: Compare pre-reform *muß-t, muss* with post-reform *muss-t, muss*. Also (very hard on the eyes of those who learned the old orthography!) cases such as *nummerieren* instead of *numerieren* because of *Nummer*.

*<sub>In the example of *Wand* – *Wände*, keeping *a* as *a* is out of the question because not all nouns that have *-e* in the plural have umlaut; *ä* is considered more orthographically similar to *a* than the identically pronounced *e*.</sub>

Comment: Interesting that these words do not have any translation into English that I can find. But from the parts (*Stamm-* and *-konstanz*) it is clear that you are right that this is "seen as [...] maintaining [...] the spelling [...] acrosss word forms [...]." It does not tell you how to pronounce it (until you have learnt how to pronounce *ä* etc.) But it does not mention its other importance - showing the change in meaning / grammatical inflection. So, for example, the *Ä* in *Äpfel* tells us two things. First, the "Stammschreibung" - it is related to *Apfel*, but it also shows it is plural.

Comment: But umlaut is a matter of pronunciation first [apfl̩ εpfl̩] and spelling second. *Epfel* would show plural just as well (and this was the way the word was written in Middle High German).

Comment: Or, to be more precise, the *A* in *Äpfel* tells it comes from *Apfel* and the *¨* tells us it is plural, clearly showing the dual value of the *Ä*. It is this second purpose that "Stammschreibung" ignores.

Comment: Except that there is no plural marker in *Epfel*. It could be a singular noun. In the same way as *men* could be in English. There is no way to tell it is plural as it rhymes with *hen*, *wren*, *wen* and *pen*, whereas *Äpfel* is clearly plural, as *men* would be if we spelt it *män*.

Comment: I don't see why *Äpfel* is clearly plural and *Epfel* is not? Note that there are words containing *ä* that are not plurals and in fact, not related to any words with *a*: *Ärger*, *Bär*, *träge*.

Comment: OK. There is a good chance that it is plural. As most words with a marked umlaut are inflected in some way. I regret I do not know how common examples like this are but I cannot find out where the *Ä* came from in the first place - *Ärger* comes from *ärgern* but [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aergern) does not explain how AHD *argerōn* changed into MHD *ergern*. What is clear is that MHD *ergern* was changed into D *ärgern* by pure "Stammschreibung", that is, preserving the root without any change in inflection. But I don't think this is usual?

Comment: How do you feel about nouns containing *ä* in the singular? *Hälfte, Käse, Lärm, März, Rätsel, Träne*. Of these, synchronically, only *Rätsel* connects to *raten*, otherwise *ä* has no discernible grammatical purpose.

Comment: I stick by my claim of "usually" but I am going to ask a separate question about your examples.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Well, *Hälfte* may at least be related to *halb*.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper OP's theory is that the diaresis above the *a* is a plural marker. I first tried to use words that have *ä* that is not related to *a* *(Bär*) to show that this is not the case. I then switched to nouns containing *ä* in the singular *(Hälfte)*. The point is that the diaresis does not indicate plural.

Comment: @DavidVogt: True, but if you point out that "*Rätsel* connects to *raten*", I think it should also be pointed out that *Hälfte* relates to *halb*. Of course, neither of these is a singular/plural pair.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper The problem is that it is not trivial to say what words are related *synchronically*. Are *Aufwand* and *aufw{e,ä}ndig*, *beh{e,ä}nde*  and *Hand*? I drew an arbitrary line and judged *Rätsel, raten* above it and *Hälfte, halb* below.